# Excel VBA Loop not Adding

Tags: vba, excel

So I am running a Do loop that cycles through a list. I used the 'index' function to calculate the value in the cell. I have a cell that is set up as the 'index' and another cell set up as the value, which is where the index function resides.

The script will start with 'index' = 1 the run. Once it's done, the script adds 1 to the 'index' and the script runs again. This continues until the cell is 0.

Most of the time this runs without any issues, but every once in a while the loop doesn't add correctly. So what happens is the loop occurs but without adding 1 to the index therefore staying on the same value over and over again. This will happen maybe 2 or 3 iterations before finally adding 1 to the index.

Any idea why this is happening? It's really frustrating because this is used to email a large audience with reports that are unique to user. So when it glitches like this, some users are receiving incorrect reports or multiple reports.

Thank you!

```
Do
    y = Worksheets("index").Range("district_num")

    xlsheet.Range("A2:Z150000").ClearContents

    Set db = OpenDatabase(DbLoc)

    SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT district_num, district_name, district_manager_name, last_name2, first_name2, " & _
    "district_mgr_job_title, district_mgr_ee_id, DM_email_email_tbl " & _
        "FROM Contacts " & _
        "WHERE district_num = " & y

    'Execute query and populate the recordset'
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

    'Paste Access data in Excel worksheet'
    xlsheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    Application.Cursor = xlDefault

    'Skips over empty zones'
    If Range("A2") <> vbNullString Then
        Call Sheet5.DM_auto_email
    Else
        Sheets("ZD_contact_list").Select    'Important to go back to the contact list so script can continue to run'
    End If

Worksheets("Index").Range("district_num_index") = Worksheets("Index").Range("district_num_index") + 1

Loop Until y = 0
```

Comment: Sorry, the issue seemed more like an excel glitch that maybe other people have experienced rather than a code issue. Because like I said, the code runs fine most of the time. But every so often, I run into this error.

Comment: It runs fine *all* the time. My guess is that `Range("A2")` is not actually a `vbNullString`. Arguably, though, if you can't even capture when this problem is occurring, then it is impossible for anyone else to replicate it, and further impossible for anyone to definitively "solve" the problem for you. Is this the same as `xlSheet.Range("A2")`?

Comment: Are you using two different named ranges? "district_num" and "district_num_index" ?  It's not clear what purpose those ranges serve.  If you want to keep a counter during the loop, just get the initial value and keep it in memory, adding one on each iteration.

Comment: @TimWilliams I suspect that may be intentional - the `"district_num_index"` cell is being **incremented** but the loop stops after having processed the iteration where `"district_num"` is zero.  That only makes sense if the single range starts with a negative value, or if there are two ranges (and probably `"district_num"` is calculated based on `"district_num_index"` - my guess is that there might be a VLOOKUP or INDEX function.)

Comment: A few missing pieces of information here.

Comment: that is correct. The district_num_index is used in the index formula to find the district_num value from a list. It seems that when the script goes to add 1 to the district_num_index, the math doesn't occur until the script has run a few times. That failure to increase the district_num_index is what is causing the issues here.

Comment: why are you using a cell formula to look up the district number? ... use code to iterate district names in the list directly  ... `for each dist in districts .... run query ... send email ...next dist`